# Attempt to refresh Div using Ajax doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So I'm trying to refresh the entries of a database when submitting a form via Ajax. The entries are in a div.

This is the code 've tried for refreshing only that div. But it doesn't work.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(function () {

            $('form').on('submit', function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: '<?php if(isset($id)){echo "update.php";} else {echo "create.php";}?>',
                    data: $('form').serialize(),
                    success: function () {
                        $(entries).fadeOut(800, function(){
                            entries.html(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000);

                        });
                    }
                });

            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

and this is the div i want to reload:

```
<div class="container" id="entries">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col pb-3">
        <h2>Einträge</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
require_once('./read.php');

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <div class="row mb-3">
            <div class="col">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $row["name"] ?>" disabled>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-1">
                            <a href="recipe.php?ID=<?php echo $row["ID"] ?>" class="btn btn-warning">Ansehen</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }
} else { ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <p>Keine Einträge in der Datenbank!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }
?>
```

Can somebody help me out with this?

Comment: There is nothing in that form. it is disabled

Answer (score 0):

`entries` is not defined... if you want to select div with id `entries`, you need to use `"#entries"` selector, like this:

```
$('#entries').fadeOut(800, function(){
    $('#entries').html(msg).fadeIn();
});
```

`delay()` should be before `fadeIn()`, not after... it means that it waits 2000ms before `fadeIn()`...

```
$('#entries').fadeOut(800, function(){
    $('#entries').html(msg).delay(2000).fadeIn();
});
```

PS1. In my opinion there is no need to delay it at all.

PS2. I would use `fadeTo()` zero opacity instead. So it wouldn't remove the element from viewport.

Comment: thanks for your comment! It's now working that the div changes but it's inserting the echo from update.php or create.php instead of reloading the content of the div

Comment: what do you mean by inserting the echo? I noticed you aren't passing the result to success function... should be `success: function(msg){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get "msg" parameter and change selector for '#entries'

```
success: function (msg) {
    $('#entries').fadeOut(800, function(){                
        $('#entries').html(msg).fadeIn().delay(2000);
    });
 }
```